# Proving that an infinite set is uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I've been doing some practice questions for my course and I found the following question quite difficult to understand.

> Prove that the following set is uncountable
>
> $B_\infty = \{ s \in B : s \text{ is an infinite binary sequence}\}$

To my knowledge, for a set to be countable it must be onto or one-to-one. Thus, I think to prove something to be uncountable, we can either prove that the set is not onto or one-to-one. Any help or hints are greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint: Cantor's diagonal argument

Comment: Functions are onto or one-to-one.  I've never heard of a onto or one-to-one set.

Comment: What does it mean for a set to be onto?  What does it mean for a set to be one-to-one?

Comment: For a set S to be countable there must exist an injection from N -> S, where N is the set of natural numbers.

Comment: @Cameron: The other way around. Injection from $S$ into $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 4):

Proceed by contradiction. Let's say you can somehow map every binary sequence to a natural number. Can you construct a binary sequence that wasn't mapped? Lost's hint in the comments on Cantor's diagonalization argument is needed.

Also, you should know that for a set to be (infinitely) countable, that means there exists an injection(one-to-one) from the set to the natural numbers.